# Why doesn't activity been invoked when received sms?

Tags: android-intent

I am using SMSReceiver class for receiving the sms. My main class code is:

```
package com.example.receivertest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
//---get the SMS message passed in---
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";            
if (bundle != null)
{
    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
        str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
        str += " :";
        str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        str += "\n";        
    }
    //---display the new SMS message---
    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(str.startsWith("aaa")){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("msg",str);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
        context.startActivity(i);
        this.abortBroadcast();
    }

}

 }
```

manifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.receivertest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I know there was one asked the similar question last time. But i like to know how to invoke an activity when it received a specific message..
My problem is no any activity being invoked but only the incoming messages in inbox..
Any one knows what's wrong with it?

Comment: Anyone knows what problem it is?